# How do I embed a link to an Opportunity in an email template?

Tags: workflow, configuration

I created a workflow that emails our Director requesting his approval on a quoted project. He would like the ability to select a link that can take him directly to that Opportunity and would also like the ability to view the attached Excel spreadsheet with the quote information. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could follow these steps for your requirement.

- create a Custom formula field which will display Opportunity record as hyperlink

  `HYPERLINK( '/' + OpportunityId, Opportunity.Name,'_blank')`
- create a HTML email template and use that field as follows

  `Link to Opportunity: {!Quote.Custom_Opportunity_Id__c}`
- Select the template from your email.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use {!Opportunity.Link} in your email template which will include a link to that opportunity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

We have used this in our email templates:

```
Details: {!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND(".com/",$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+3)}/{!relatedTo.Id}
```